# Numeros de validación

Tags: c

Lo que quiero es validar solo la entrada de números **mayores o iguales que 0**.

Y en caso que ponga un número negativo que vuelva a pedir un nuevo número pero no se cómo ponerlo soy nuevo en estas cosas. Así como si alguien pone -5 que diga "Ingrese otro nùmero los negativos son invalidos" o algo así y vuelva a pedir otro nùmero. Se que se debe utilizar como un do while o if pero no se como hacerlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141593

int main ( ) {    
  double RAD, AREA;

  printf( "Introducir radio de la esfera\n" );
  scanf( "%lf", &RAD );

   AREA = 4 * PI * pow( RAD, 2 ); 

   printf( "El valor de la esfera es igual a %f", AREA );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Intenta usar lo que se conoce como centinelas o banderas, es ecir, le asignas un valor inválido al inicio y mientras tenga ese valor inválido lo sigues preguntando con el while.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

double pi=3.141593;
double RAD, AREA;

    do{

        cout<<"Introducir radio de la esfera: ";
        cin>>RAD;

    }while(RAD <= 0);//Si rad es menor o igual a 0 , pedirá que introduzca otra ves el radio

    AREA= 4* pi * pow(RAD,2);

    cout<<"El valor de la esfera es igual a: "<<AREA<<endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, creo q así se ve mejor  y mas simplificado

Comment: Gracias Manuel Castillo. Solo una pregunta màs. Que quiere decir 'cin' y ''cin.get' y "end 1" para que se utilizan o es su función

Comment: El cin alamacena datos ya sea del tipo entero o char y las puedes llamar usando el nombre de la variable

Comment: cin.get , lo uso para que no se cierre el programa

Comment: Endl para dar un salto al texto

Comment: Lo mio es lenguaje c++, no te compliques

Answer (score 0):

> Lo que quiero es validar solo la entrada de números **mayores o iguales que 0**.

Pues usa un tipo de datos sin signo:

```
unsigned int dato;
scanf("%u", &dato); // %u lee enteros sin signo.
```

Pero por los cálculos que realizas, parece que necesitas números decimales, los cuales no tienen versión sin signo, así que tendrás que comprobar el resultado tras leer:

```
double dato;
do
{
    scanf("%lf", &dato);
while (dato < .0); // Repetir mientras el dato sea menor que cero.
```